# No compiler is provided in this environment with jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm getting this error when I try a **Jenkins** build on a **maven** project:

```
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

The **java** and **maven** plugin are installed automatically, after several research, I couldn't find a solution!

Does anyone have ever face this issue?

Answer (score 21):

Go To Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK. Provide path to the JDK under JAVA_HOME field.

Comment: In this section I've choosen install automatically

Comment: check the jdk path in the JDK section of the configuration to see if its pointing to JRE rather than JDK

Comment: I did this change : replace Install automatically with the path to my open JDK but still have the same error

Comment: see if you have javac in the JAVA_HOME. The path should be <path_to_jdk>/jdkx.x

Comment: Yes, my JAVA_HOME is : JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/" and I can find the javac under the directory bin/ of this path

Comment: Actually, the javac is under the bin/ directory of my JAVA_HOME. The problem was that I was pointing to java 1.6 where no javac was defined. So I had to change the JAVA_HOME to the right one with the javac under the /bin/ directory

Answer (score 10):

First make sure the your Job in Jenkins doesn't use the "default Jdk" by going to the job: 
Press on Configure - > and roll to the JDK section - and make sure you have JDK configure instead of Default.

if you don't have it - go back to Jenkins - > Manage Jenkins -> Configure System - > Jdk and map your Jdk Root for Jenkins.

when you finish that - go back and choose your map JDK - and everything will work.

Comment: Thank  you selecting globally configured correct "JDK" value solved my problem,

Answer (score 6):

Go To Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration.

Now click on "JDK installations.." under JDK

Uncheck Install automatically

Provide path to the JDK under JAVA_HOME field.

Refer:-

[image]

Answer (score 4):

May be this issue is already resolved by now. But I had the same issue recently and I have the following settings in my `Jenkins`. This happened in my `Windows 10` `Jenkins` installation.

1. Installed `JDK` at `C:\Java\Jdk8` and made `JAVA_HOME` point to this location. Also make sure that PATH env variable has %JAVA_HOME%\bin.
2. Installed `JRE` (which comes bundled with `Oracle JDK` installation) at `C:\Program Files\Java\JRE`.
3. Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System
   [image]
4. Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration
   [image]

**# javac -version**

```
javac 1.8.0_201
```

**# java -version**

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

**# mvn -v**

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T14:41:47-04:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Java\jdk8\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I believe the change that fixed the problem was the addition of env variables under `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System`.

Comment: The upper steps were enough to solve the problem for freestyle projects. For Pipelines the mentioned step

"Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Environment Variables"

was the one that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Enter http://localhost:8080/configure. Then go Jenkins Location.

Jenkins Configuration:

[image]

Environment variable configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might not have set JAVA_HOME in Jenkin installed server. Set JAVA_HOME and restart your Jenkin server.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message you either do not have a [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) installed or you need to configure Jenkins's CLASSPATH to point to your JDK installation.

Comment: I've already set up a JDK installation in JENKINS ( JDK install automatically), but where to configure Jenkins CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 0):

Just give the JDK path in Jenkins Global Tool configurations, i.e the path where we have kept the jdk file in the di

Comment: Your answer seems to be incompl

Answer (score 0):

IF you don't want to add anythig in Global tools Configuration, add new environment variable `java.home` in the Jenkins slave configuration as maven detects `java.home` and not `JAVA_HOME`.

`java.home` ---> `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre`

[image]