# Compilation error while running maven project via jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I am running the selenium maven project via eclipse my script is running without any issue but when I am trying to run build via Jenkins getting below compilation error.

```
Started by user karishmayadav
Building in workspace E:\Selenium2018\setup\jenkins\workspace\FreeCRM
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 54515
[FreeCRM] $ java -cp E:\Selenium2018\setup\jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar;E:\Selenium2018\setup\jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\testmaven1\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;E:\Selenium2018\setup\jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\testmaven1/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main E:\Selenium2018\setup\jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\testmaven1 E:\Selenium2018\setup\jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.25.jar E:\Selenium2018\setup\jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar E:\Selenium2018\setup\jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar 54515
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f E:\Selenium2018\SeleniumPrograms\FreeCRM\pom.xml clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< org.com.FreeCRM:FreeCRM >-----------------------
[INFO] Building FreeCRM 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ FreeCRM ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\Selenium2018\SeleniumPrograms\FreeCRM\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ FreeCRM ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\Selenium2018\SeleniumPrograms\FreeCRM\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ FreeCRM ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to E:\Selenium2018\SeleniumPrograms\FreeCRM\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.774 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-19T13:28:13+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project FreeCRM: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[JENKINS] Archiving E:\Selenium2018\SeleniumPrograms\FreeCRM\pom.xml to org.com.FreeCRM/FreeCRM/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/FreeCRM-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Sending e-mails to: karishma.qaengr@gmail.com
ERROR: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:131)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.execute(MailSender.java:106)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenMailer.end(MavenMailer.java:76)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuilder.end(AbstractMavenBuilder.java:104)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:885)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:286)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 16 more
channel stopped
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Sending e-mails to: karishma.qaengr@gmail.com
ERROR: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:131)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.execute(MailSender.java:106)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.cleanUp(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1094)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1862)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:286)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 13 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am not sure whether is there any deopendency gettng missed in pom.xml file.below is pom.xml file
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      4.0.0

```
  <groupId>org.com.FreeCRM</groupId>
  <artifactId>FreeCRM</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>FreeCRM</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Sometimes eclipse could fooled us. Please execute your maven commands in a clean folder and using a command line. Also what command are you executing?

Comment: @cgrim solution provided in the post [Maven compilation error with jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213038/maven-compilation-error-with-jenkins) solves my issue.Thanks!!

Comment: @JRichards In jenkins under global tool configurations there was no jdk path mentioned ,providing jdk path resolves the issue.Thanks!!