# Jenkins - No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, pom.xml

I am trying to do build install on my Jenkins and I am getting the error:

> No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

I have set the JDK path both in `Global Tool Configuration` and `Configure System`. I tried giving the JAVA_HOME in both `Global Tool Configuration` and `Configure System` too.

I've tried these steps:

- Go to Jenkins dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Add Environment Variable :
  JAVA_HOME and value
- Go to Jenkins dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Configuration Tool -> Add JDKs -> unchecked install automatically -> provided JAVA_HOME and value.
- Also checked in the system of your windows... System -> advanced settings -> environment variables. Set the PATH : Append with the folder path of the jdk

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

Comment: what is the JAVA_HOME value? the error is  clear you are configuring a jre path instead of a jdk path

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201

Comment: For debugging, first try to run `java -version` on the agent in a cmd. If ok, run the command `bat 'set'` inside your Jenkins pipeline script to get a print of the whole environment variables, check if the `PATH` variable contains your path to the java executable.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dummy job which would do, as commented a java -version.

The goal is to check if, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358803/6309), a JRE (like `C:\Program Files\Java\JRE`) would not come *before* a  (for instance) `C:\Java\Jdk8`, when executing said job.